# Extract problem and solution from files and create problem collection

Tags: external-files, exercises

I have a set of problems and solutions, and I wish to include (some of) them in several different documents. I would like to be able to choose if the solutions should be presented last, or immediate after the problem formulation.

A possibility is to put each problem and solution in a separate file,
and then have some command

```
\includepart{filename.tex}{problem}
```

and

```
\includepart{filename.tex}{solution}
```

where `\includepart{file}{env}` includes say everything between
`\begin{env}`and `\end{env}`.

Is there a simple way to do this? Are there better solutions to this?
This seems to be a common problem, but I have not found something that does exactly this.

Comment: Have, a look to the `comment` package and the definition of versions and the command `\includecomment{}` and `\excludecomment{}`. http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/comment/comment.pdf

Comment: The [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) package allows to include problems and their solutions from external files selectively.

Comment: The exsheets looks nice, however, is there an easy way to install it on a linux system? It seems to rely on some experimental packages. Is exsheets considered stable?

Comment: I tried installing exsheets (not particularly easy),

Comment: If you use the `answers` package you can have all the problems and solutions in one file, then choose (in the preamble, with a switch or by commenting code) whether the answers appear with the problems, at the end of the document, or in a separate document.

Comment: I tried installing exsheets (not particularly easy), but had some trouble with it (numbering of exercises does not work, get a strange 'undefined control sequence error' on a vanilla installation.

Comment: The package `answers` do not seem to be able to include only certain problems. It is all or nothing...

Comment: @Paxinum the `exsheets` package is part of both an up to date TeX Live 2013 and MiKTeX. You shouldn't need to have to install it manually...

Comment: @cgneider Ah, is it in the Ubuntu repository? Kile did not have exsheets installed, so I thought it was something non-official.

Comment: @Paxinum Kile is an editor not a TeX distribution. I have no idea if it is in the Ubuntu repository... I don't have Ubuntu and if I had I'd still use the ['vanilla' TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) so I can't answer that

Comment: @cgneider Yes, just curious what version of TeX-Live that is installed by default... Oh well, gonna experiment a bit more.

Comment: Got the install to work, turns out my system used 2009 version and not 2013. I'm ready to accept an answer with `exsheets`.

Comment: @Paxinum I'm not notified if you misspell my name ;) I'll post an example soon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) provides means to selectively include problems and their respective solutions from external files.

Let's say we have an external file `exercises.tex` with the following contents:

```
% question `test1'
\begin{question}[ID=test1]
  First sample question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  First sample solution
\end{solution}

% question `test2'
\begin{question}[ID=test2]
  Second sample question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  Second sample solution
\end{solution}

% question `test3'
\begin{question}[ID=test3]
  Third sample question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  Third sample solution
\end{solution}
```

Then the main file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\begin{document}
\includequestions[IDs={test1,test3}]{exercises.tex}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

The default behaviour is *not* to print the solutions. This can be changed by setting an option. The following file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{solution/print=true}
\begin{document}
\includequestions[exclude={test2}]{exercises.tex}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

This also demonstrates that you can selectively *exclude* questions from being printed.

If you want to separate exercises and solutions that's also possible by calling `\printsolutions` where you want them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\begin{document}
\section*{Exercises}
\includequestions[IDs={test2,test3}]{exercises.tex}
\section*{Solutions}
\printsolutions
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: It's simple and very useful. How could I change the words "Exercise" and "Solution" to other (not English, in fact Hungarian) words? I tried with babel package but it is not correct. More explicitly, I want "1. feladat" instead of "Exercise 1." .

Comment: @vesszabo There are two possibilities both described in the manual: a) there are options to set the names manually b) there is a way to add translations that will be used if the `babel` language is chosen. If you read the part about internationalization in the manual you might consider sending an email to the author (me) to add the translations to the package.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I prefer method a). 
Only one question remained open. Hungarian is an "exotic" language, and would be desirable to put the number at the beginning, "1. Exercise"  instead of "Exercise 1.", if it is not too complicated.

Comment: That's quite easy. You just need to choose the appropriate headings instance. Look for the section about styling the exercises in the manual.

Comment: It works well. If you don't mind, I ask two new questions. (1) Is it possible to reset the counter number to 1 after "Exercise 5."? I found only the counter-format. (2) Is it possible to write my own "\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}" and insert in the  preamble of the .tex file? I want to obtain "Solution" without number. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @vesszabo of course you can reset the counter. It's a normal LaTeX counter named `question`. (This means `\setcounter`, `\stepcounter` and all the other commands can be used as with every other counter.)

Comment: @vesszabo yes you can define your own headings instance. Indeed users are encouraged to do so. The long list of existing instances serves two purposes: a) show the existing instances b) serve as examples for defining own instances.

Comment: Thanks for your help and Happy New Year. The problem of counter was solved easily. I also found the solution for the headings instance, to write the instance was also easy. The only problem is that (if I understand correctly) you handle the headings together not considering separately the question and solution environment. It results a huge amount of \SetupExSheets{headings=....} . Is there a simpler method?

Comment: @vesszabo You can use `\RenewQuSolPair` to set individual heading styles for questions and solutions: `\RenewQuSolPair{question}[headings=foo]{solution}[headings=bar]`. See section 18 of the manual.

Comment: Very thanks.It works well if there is 1 version of the exercise sheet.You write in sec 11 about \PrintSolutionsTF, etc, "They might in handy if you want two versions of an exercise sheet, one with exercises and one with the solutions". My case is: 1 with exes to students and 1 with exes and sols to my assistants in 1 pdf file. Sorry for me, but I don't understand what you say about \PrintSolutionsTF,T,F. My poor method is 
\includequestions[IDs={q1}]{power.tex}
etc,
\setcounter{question}{0}
\includequestions[IDs={q1}]{power.tex}
\SetupExSheets{headings=runin-text}
\printsolutions[byID={q1}]